# good practice in mail and FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING

Tags: php, email, filter-var

I use this to send email:

```
$_POST['message'] = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
// …    
mail($mail_to, $subject, $message,  'MIME-Version: 1.0' ."\r\n" .'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n".'From: '.$_POST['email'] . "\r\n" .'Reply-To: '.$_POST['email']. "\r\n" );
```

It works, but the quote looks like this: `&#34;`.
There is an option in [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for quote but is it secure?

Comment: Is there a need to sanitize the message? Are you inserting it to the database before sending to email?

Comment: @benoít: dqlopez's question is good. You should elaborate on what you mean by the question "is it secure?"

Comment: As others suggested, you need to be more precise with what you mean about "secure".

Comment: If you're sending it as a *plaintext* message and it is correctly interpreted by all receivers as plain text, there's no vulnerability to be afraid of.

Comment: @dqlopez No database, just sending mail… 
Do I have to do something for message ? or just 'FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL' for from or maybe use 
'<?php
$from = $_POST["sender"];
if (eregi("(\r|\n)", $from)) {
die("Why ?? :(");
}
?>'

Comment: `eregi()` is deprecated, you should (must) not use it. As deceze stated, there's no need to be afraid of as I can see you specify the content to be `plain/text`. Regarding the sender, you can sanitize it using that `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` or probably not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you send the mail as HTML instead of plain text, the sanitized character will be displayed correctly. One can do this in your code by changing:

```
'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8'
```

to

```
'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'
```